# Condition to the holomorphy of a complex function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, complex-numbers, correlation-functions, analyticity

In Witten's note https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993, during the proof of Reeh-Schlieder theorem, he made an arguement that considering a function
$$g(u)=\langle\chi|\phi(x_1)\dots e^{\mathrm{i}Hu}\phi(x_n)|\Omega\rangle\,.$$
Because the hamiltonian $H$ is bounded below by $0$, the operator $\exp(\mathrm{i}Hu)$ is holomorphic for $u$ in the upper half plane so that the function $g(u)$ is also holomorphic. Why the holomorphy of this function is connected to the boundness of $H$ and the reigon of $u$? I suppose that the upper half plane limit of $u$ is to stop the term $\exp(-Im(u)H )$ diverge to infinity, yet I am still confused by its relation to the holomorphy of the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\psi, \phi$ be two Hilbert space vectors. According to the spectral theorem, a signed measure $\mu_{\psi,\phi}$ with bounded variation exists such that
$$\langle \psi, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}uH} \phi\rangle = \int_{\sigma(H)} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}u\lambda} \mathrm{d} \mu_{\psi,\phi}(\lambda),$$
where $\sigma(H)$ is the spectrum of $H$. Thus, the complex derivative of $\langle \psi, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}uH} \phi\rangle$ can be computed as follows:
$$\partial_u \langle \psi, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}uH} \phi\rangle = \int_{\sigma(H)} \mathrm{i} \lambda \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}u\lambda} \mathrm{d} \mu_{\psi,\phi}(\lambda).$$
If the imaginary part of $u$ is strictly positive (i.e. $\Im(u) > 0)$, the integral on the r.h.s. is convergent:
$$\left| \int_{\sigma(H)} \mathrm{i} \lambda \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}u\lambda} \mathrm{d} \mu_{\psi,\phi}(\lambda) \right| 
\leq \int_{\sigma(H)} |\lambda| \mathrm{e}^{-\Im(u)\lambda} \mathrm{d} |\mu_{\psi,\phi}|(\lambda) < \infty,$$
where I used that $\sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(H)}|\lambda| \mathrm{e}^{-\Im(u)\lambda}$ is finite (this uses that the spectrum of $H$ is bounded from below and that the exponential decays faster than any polynomial). This ensures that the complex derivative of $\langle \psi, \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}uH} \phi\rangle$ exists.